# wiring lights and continuing the circuit to another light circuit

Tags: wiring, code-compliance

[image]

I have 1 switch running the 1st 3 lights then the next switch runs 1 light.  I mocked this up with spare wire and it works, but is it OK to do it like this?

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all, that's exactly how it should be done.